# Save the modified Property file inside WAR deployed on server

Tags: apache, jsf, properties, configuration, save

We are trying to use Apache PropertiesConfiguration in our project using JSF and JBoss.

My property file is located inside a package say demo.prop by the name of Prop1.prop

Inside my WAR file the same is present under /WEB-INF/classes/demo/prop/Prop1.prop

Using

**FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/demo/prop/Prop1.prop");**

I am able to fetch the property file. So when I try to extract a string from the property file using

```
PropertiesConfiguration pc1=new PropertiesConfiguration(a);
                String s1=(String)pc1.getProperty("User_Name");
```

I am able to get the proper string. Using set property method I am able to set the property also.

```
pc1.setProperty("User_Name", "hardcodedString");
```

But I am not able to save the FILE back to this location. No matter what I do it is not able to save the file using **pc1.save**.

Can anyone please try to tell me how can I save this file back to its original location so that the changes done in the property file remain as it is.

Comment: So you're trying to save "Prop1.prop" which is placed inside a WAR archive? Apart from that being problematic (as the WAR is compressed) I don't think that is a good idea. Maybe save the modified properties to another prop file placed in an accessible location and load both files (the modified one second) - so the changes in the modified prop file override the original ones.

Comment: Agreed. I know its not a good practice to do modification inside a WAR. But I need to do it irrespective. Also can you elaborate more on the alternative you provided? On application startup I am reading the prop file using Bundle . How do you recommend I then reload it..Please note I still need to load it initially from a bundle and possible again from the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the WAR file is a bad idea (for example, some web servers may notice the file
modification an redeploy your app, there may be problems when the server explodes the war on deployment etc.)

I would suggest applying an alternative approach - some possibilities are:

1. Place the properties in a database table, so they can be easily modified
2. Use an external properties file for overriding your  "Prop1.prop" file settings. You can pull this off for example as follows. Assume that the default property values are bundled in your WAR and the modified values are saved to some other path, which is defined using a system property - let say it's called CONFIG_LOCATION. Now after loading your properties from the bundle you read them also from this external "overrides.prop" file - this overrides your defaults from "Prop1.prop":

   PropertiesConfiguration pc1=new PropertiesConfiguration(a);
   try(FileReader propReader = new FileReader(System.getenv().get("CONFIG_FILES") +"/overrides.prop"){
       pc1.load(propReader);
   }

   When you need to save changes, you do that to "overrides.prop" - this will save all
   the properties, not only the changed ones, but that should have no negative effects.

Comment: What if the database is not available? For this reason alone I prefer just plain old text files. Easy to connect to, easy to install, easy to encrypt, easy to edit, easy to recreate, easy to migrate. Some serious postitiives there. Overall some good advise but the Db comes with some risks.

Comment: True, but that's basically the case in my suggestion #2.

Comment: Like I said good advise just be careful of using a database as "easy" persistent storage for a small amount of configurations. It really depends on the situation. I have seen people install entire servers so they can have  configuration data stored in. Now if you have a lot of configurations that needed to be in a HA solution a text file is going to be a bit primitive.